# Is there a way to assign an array of values in a column to one variable?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to assign all the values in a column to a variable, currently, it is not reading them in correctly. There are no compiling errors or runtime errors right now, just a logical error. Any insight would be very helpful please

I have already tried creating them as objects, and using "Set".

```
Dim countrow As Integer
Dim P(), T() As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim numrow As Long

numrow = Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
P = Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(numrow, 1)).Value
T = Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(numrow, 2)).Value

ReDim P(numrow) As Variant
ReDim T(numrow) As Variant

countrow = 0

For i = 3 To numrow - 1
   If P(i) = 5 And T(i) = 100 Then
      countrow = countrow + 1                       
   End If
Next i

MsgBox (countrow)
```

I expect an output of 25, but the actual output is 0. Meaning it is not reading in the true value in each cell. I am trying to count how many rows satisfy both P=5 and T=100 in their cells.

Comment: when you do `ReDim P(numrow) As Variant
ReDim T(numrow) As Variant` it is clearing the array, get rid of these lines.

Comment: And remember that when bulk filling the row 3 on the sheet just became item (1,1) in the array. change your for to `For i = lbound(p,1) to ubound(p,1)` and the if: `If P(i,1) = 5 And T(i,1) = 100 Then` because the arrays are two dimensional even though they are single columns.

Comment: But I do not see why a simple countifs will not do this:  `countrow = Application.COUNTIFS(Range("A:A"),5,Range("B:B"),100)` and skip the whole array.

Comment: And I believe that `numrow = Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row` assumes column A, just in case your data moves and column A is no longer the deciding factor on number of columns.